# Invalid color value ?android:colorControlNormal

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a drawable resource file like this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="?android:colorControlNormal"
        android:pathData="M9,11L7,11v2h2v-2zM13,11h-2v2h2v-2zM17,11h-2v2h2v-2zM19,4h-1L18,2h-2v2L8,4L8,2L6,2v2L5,4c-1.11,0 -1.99,0.9 -1.99,2L3,20c0,1.1 0.89,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L21,6c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM19,20L5,20L5,9h14v11z"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
</vector>
```

On Gradle Build, Error is as follows:

```
Invalid color value ?android:colorControlNormal
at com.android.ide.common.resources.MergedResourceWriter$FileGenerationWorkAction.run
```

**What I tried:**  I changed it to `?attr/colorControlNormal`, but still same error
I am stuck at this. Can somebody help?

Comment: what is your minSdkVersion in gradle file?

Comment: I don't want to change minSdk version as I forked this from an opensource repository.

Answer (score 3):

`?attr/colorControlNormal` works for me. As I could see from your code you have `tools:targetApi="lollipop"` which means your `minSdk` is lower than API 21. Vector drawables are supported down to API 21. Before that Gradle generates PNGs for that vector drawables. By using theme attributes like `?attr/colorControlNormal` means your drawable color could vary depending on the theme of its context. Therefore gradle **could not** generate PNGs for it as it doesn't know about the context.

The solution for this is either update the **minSdk** version to be atleast 21 or use a static color or static color reference. For example: `android:fillColor="@color/someColor` or `android:fillColor="#FF00FF00"`

Comment: Do you think It could happen because I updated my Gradle. I forked this from an opensource repository. I can't just change the minSdk version.

Comment: I actually don't exactly know what this 'FileGenerationWorkAction' Gradle task does and how it works under the hood. It might be changed during different Gradle versions, but I couldn't be sure about it. Sorry

Comment: I just restored my Gradle plugin to previous version and It worked without any errors. But as you said "gradle could not generate PNGs for it as it doesn't know about the context." then how does Gradle know now after I downgraded my Gradle plugin?

Comment: Maybe it's generating based on your launch activity or your AndroidManifest themes. But in the 'newer' versions they removed that because themes could be set runtime. As I said I don't know how it works under the hood and I'm just speculating.

Comment: my `minSdk` is 23, but there is the same problem...

Comment: I think this is caused by the version of gradle .  When my gradle version and its plugin version is gradle-6.1.1-all and gradle-4.0.2,my vector will work succes.

But when I change it to gradle-6.5-all and gradle-4.1.3, or gradle-6.7.1-all and gradle-4.2.2. my vector diagram doesn't run successfully, which surprises me!

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated the Gradle Plugin to the latest version, restore it to `3.6.1` as It seems this is working till version `'3.6.1'`.